# Will child_added still work if some entries are restricted by the security rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a ref pointing to privateMessages like below:

`messagesRef: firebase.database().ref("privateMessages")`

Below is a listener function for any `child_added` event in `/privateMessages`:

```
this.state.messagesRef.on("child_added", snap => {
...
})
```

For security rules, not all records in /privacyMessages are accessible to a certain logged-in user. So in this case, will the listener function still work? I've tried but seems the listener function not getting executed. Please kindly let me know where went wrong and how to fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, a listener on `messagesRef` will be rejected unless the user has full read access to `messagesRef`.

The important thing to realize that [security rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) on their own. They merely ensure that all access is authorized. And in your scenario, the access would only be authorized if the user has read access to all of `messagesRef`.

If you want a user to be able to read only a subset of the data, you'll need two things:

1. A query to read only that data.
2. Security rules that only allow data query.

This is described in the documentation on [query based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules), which includes a useful example too including both the code and the rules.